# Pause Conditional Formatting but keep the last changes

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting, gantt-chart

I have a GANTT chart in excel on one sheet that uses conditionally formatting to conditionally fill 7 different colors for about 50 rows over about 120 periods(columns) per month.

As you can imagine, this creates a very slow worksheet.  I have considered reducing the number of periods but currently have 2 days per period and any more than that might cause the calendar to look inaccurate.

I want to see if I can "pause" the conditionally formatting so that the conditions are not running constantly in the background but I'd want to keep the formatting that was applied before pausing.

The "Stop If True" feature gets me halfway there by creating a condition to stop all the formatting when a cell says "Freeze" but it doesn't leave the formatting in place.

Any thoughts on how to do this?  Ideally without using Macros as this file will eventually be on a sharedrive and I don't want to deal with the permissions issues with every user.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To hold the conditional formatting color is not very easy.  It requires the addition of a button on your sheet to hold the colors.
The button will execute code (see below) that will copy the current conditional formatting color to the cell interior color.
A cell with the name "HOLD_b" should also be placed on the sheet. The value of this cell "TRUE" or "FALSE" must be used for the 1st conditional formatting with the "Stop If True" checked.
What you have so far is good, just add that cell, and the button with the following code.

```
' HOLD CONDITIONAL FORMATING COLOR
' Button Click that will alternate between two states
' 1- hold the current conditional formatting color
' 2- Resume conditional formatting
' A conditional formatting rule must be set on the "HOLD_b" cell    
' value to set the formatting to "clear"
' It must be set at the top with the option "stop if true" checked
        
    Private Sub Set_Color_Click()
    Dim MyRangeArea As Range
    Dim MyRange As Range
    
    '=====  Set your Area Here ==============
    Set MyRangeArea = Range("I6:M10")
    '========================================
            
        If Range("HOLD_b") Then  'HOLD_b is a cell to control formatting
            For Each MyRange In MyRangeArea
                MyRange.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
            Next MyRange
            Range("HOLD_b") = False
        Else
            For Each MyRange In MyRangeArea
                MyRange.Interior.Color = MyRange.Item(1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
            Next MyRange
            Range("HOLD_b") = True
        End If
    End Sub
```